# jQuery not working while selecting and changing an objects class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I´ve tried a lot of code to select my #slider and its children which are images and change their class, my last try is this one:

## INDEX.php

```
   <center>
            <div id="slider">

                <image class="slider" id="shown" src="img/img1.jpg"/>
                <image class="slider" id="notShown" src="img/img3.jpg"/>
                <image class="slider" id="notShown" src="img/img2.jpg"/>

            </div>
   </center>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/slider.js"></script>
```

## SLIDER.js

```
$(function(){

            console.log("HEY");
            $('#slider image').each(function(){
                   $(this).removeAttr('class');
                   });
            });
```

Comment: Are you sure that `$(this)` refers to current `image`?

Comment: You have not included jQuery.js

Comment: Also, where is the opening tag of </center>

Comment: Use `<img` tag instead of `<image` and include jquery

Comment: jQuery.js is included in the <head> of index.php do i need to add it too in slider.js?

Answer (score 1):

The tag to use is `img` rather than `image`.

Some other things:

1. `<center>` tag is deprecated.
2. `<img>` should always have `alt` attribute.
3. Try not to use the same names for ID and class, e.g. you have one `#slider` and three `.slider` elements. This can be very prone to errors.
4. You should never have duplicate IDs, e.g. you have two elements with ID `notShown`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the hints, but i found the real problem:

I needed to remove the ID rather than the class to make all images visible, because my "notShown" ID made the images display none not the class.

Anyways thanks by making my coding syntax better.